# CSS3 + 'display' toggle bug in Chrome?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

For a few months I've used the CSS3 + selector to apply CSS to certain elements.

Here's a demo of my use: http://jsfiddle.net/HB5Bz/2/

In IE and older versions of Chrome when hovering on the edit icon it would display the menu, but in the most recent version of Chrome it doesn't by default. But when toggling 'display' manually via the 'Elements' tab in dev tools it works fine. Is this a bug with Chrome? Or have they introduced a new system for doing this?

The line in question is:

```
#profile_feed_post_edit:hover + .profile_feed_post_edit_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The demo is buggy even in FF (ok, in Chrome doesn't show even up)

Comment: +1 playing around and still no luck. Good question!

Comment: Interesting...   same experience here.   Works great in Safari (ahhh, my trusted Safari... ) but not so much in Chrome.   Hmm...    playing with the code now, will see if I have any luck.

Comment: Seems like at the moment the user hovers the (previously hidden) icon, the icon's `+` (next sibl.) gets unbound to the icon `hover` event. Bug, but in any case, it's not the way to build nested :hovers .

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the toggling of `display:hidden;` to `display:block` is stopping the propogation of the hover event to the parent element for some unknown reason. It works if you go into the Chrome dev tools and force hover on the parent element.

As a result, the easiest fix would be to toggle `visibility:hidden` to `visibility:visible` for the icon on the right (also toggling the cursor). This fixes the problem in Chrome and works the same for other browsers. The only difference: the object still affects your layout when hidden

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/HB5Bz/3/)

As Roko shows, there is a way if you change your HTML to allow the toggling of `display` to work correctly, but I think it'd be a good idea to notify the Chrome guys anyway

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it:
Don't use nested `:hover` and than try to target `>` (children) or `+` (next sibling) elements.

To properly maintain the hover state it has to be bound to a common parent element,

```
<grandparent>      // hover triggers 'parent' to show up

    <UI image>

    <parent>       // initially hidden, hover triggers HIDDEN to show up!
       <UI icon>
       <HIDDEN until PARENT is hovered>
    </parent>

</grandparent>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hitofixi/1/edit)**

```
<div class="feed_photo_portrait">  

  <img src="//placehold.it/150x110/cf5&text=IMAGE"> 
  <div class="edit">
    <img class="edit-ico" src="//placehold.it/50x50/f0f&text=EDIT" >
    <ul class="edit-options">
       <li><a href="#">Make Profile Picture</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Delete This Photo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.feed_photo_portrait{
  background:#eee;
}
.edit{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
}

.feed_photo_portrait:hover > .edit{
  display:block;
}

.edit-options{
  display:none;
  background:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 115px;
  top: 12px;
  right: 8px;
}

/* Don't use .edit-ico for the hover but the common parent .edit */
.edit:hover > .edit-options{
  display:block;
}
```